# Howto inject local css into webpage

Tags: css, local

I would like to test out CSS on a webpage that I don't have direct access to. Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

So I write my CSS, and on save, that code is used on the webpage. 
Of cause this will only happen on my local machine

Comment: Asking for recommendation of a tool is considered as off-topic mate. Hence, voted to close.

Comment: so where can I write off topic questions ?

Comment: on your desk and give it to your wife or girlfriend, lol...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple Bookmarklet, similar to how various jQuery Injectors work.

http://mcdlr.com/css-inject/ might do the trick. For something a bit more dynamic (which takes a URL to a CSS file), check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/56c385au/) I've whipped up! It shouldn't be too hard to modify to pass in inline styles, etc..  so should be a good starting point.

```
javascript:var%20csshref=prompt('enter%20css%20url');var%20s=document.createElement('link');s.setAttribute('href',csshref);s.setAttribute('type','text/css');s.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);void(s);
```

**Re your comment...**

You can just use F12 Dev Tools. [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) and [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/gg699337(v=vs.85).aspx) are all quite good now. (My preference is Chrome).

Comment: This is not exactly waht I want. I want that things are used on webpage, everytime I save my CSS.
A lot like your link, but on file save, so I don't have to copy paste my CSS all the time

Comment: I know F12. I am a frontend developer :)